# Task.Run on method returning T VS method returning Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, asynchronous

**Scenario 1** - For each website in string list (_websites), the caller method wraps GetWebContent into a task, waits for all the tasks to finish and return results.

```
    private async Task<string[]> AsyncGetUrlStringFromWebsites()
    {
        List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        foreach (var website in _websites)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetWebsiteContent(website)));
        }

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return results;
    }

    private string GetWebContent(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = client.GetStringAsync(url);

        return content.Result;
    }
```

**Scenario 2** - For each website in string list (_websites), the caller method calls GetWebContent (returns Task< string >), waits for all the tasks to finish and return the results.

```
    private async Task<string[]> AsyncGetUrlStringFromWebsites()
    {
        List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        foreach (var website in _websites)
        {
            tasks.Add(GetWebContent(website));
        }

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return results;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetWebContent(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        return content;
    }
```

**Questions** - Which way is the correct approach and why? How does each approach impact achieving asynchronous processing?

Comment: You've asked about preferences, which is based on opinion. You should instead ask why the first one is incorrect and the second is correct? What makes them so?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Task.Run()` you occupy a thread from the thread pool and tell it to wait until the web content has been received.
Why would you want to do that? Do you pay someone to stand next to your mailbox to tell you when a letter arrives?

`GetStringAsync` already is asynchronous. The cpu has nothing to do (with this process) while the content comes in over the network.

So the second approach is correct, no need to use extra threads from the thread pool here.

Always interesting to read: [Stephen Cleary's "There is no thread"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: Additionally, the usage of `Task.Result` can lead to deadlocks.

Comment: Doesn't scenario 2 occupy a thread from the thread pool and tell it to wait? May you expand your answer please. Why is scenario 1 using more threads than scenario 2?

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN No, the second version does not use any extra thread. Please refer to the blog post I linked, Stephen Cleary's explanation is much better than I could ever write it. `await`ing the _truely_ asynchronous `GetStringAsync` does not block or use any thread, it simply returns to the caller and resumes the rest of the method after the `Task` returned by `GetStringAsync` completes.

Answer (score 1):

@René Vogt gave a great explanation.

There a minor 5 cents from my side.

In the second example there is not need to use `async` / `await` in `GetWebContent` method. You can simply return `Task<string>` (this would also reduce `async` depth).

Comment: Except that `HttpClient` should really be disposed after usage, in which case he will need to put back async/await.

Comment: HttpClient is of type IDisposable so you can dispose it, but is advised not to do this to avoid SocketExceptions being thrown. Read https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ - Furthermore, having HttpClient as a singleton doesn't respect DNS changes unless you have the correct ServicePointManager settings. The new HttpClient factory in Asp Net Core 2.1 is meant to solve all these problems - https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

Comment: It is still advisable to dispose the client if you're not going to reuse it, the article details lot more than just "do not dispose HttpClient".

Comment: Isn't async/await needed in GetWebContent method because I want to await on client.GetStringAsync(url)?

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN In this case it does not matter: `GetStringAsync()` returns a `Task<string>`. You can `await` that `Task` in your `async GetWebContent()`, which then in turn also returns a `Task<string>` or you can simply return the `Task<string>` and let the caller `await` it. That saves you a level of indirection and an extra async state machine generated by the compiler

Comment: @RenéVogt I see, thanks for the clarification. In the situation where I want to manipulate the string from 'GetStringAsync' before I return to the caller, do you think there is a case to use await on 'GetStringAsync'?

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN Yes, if you want to manipulate the string inside `GetWebContent` before returning, you need to `string s = await GetStringAsync(); string res = DoSomething(s); return res;` and to declare `GetWebContent` as `async`, too.